# Android app update : Users don't get any updates after version update on Play Store

Tags: android, apk

I have an Android app on Play Store. I updated it and its version recently. However, the my app users -

1. Did not get any update notification
2. Still saw `OPEN` app instead of `UPDATE` on Play Store app

How can I change this?

Comment: When did you upload the new version ?

Comment: More than a day ago.

Answer (score 0):

Visit your play store developer console  if the state of the app is (published) and the version is your latest uploaded version then

It's OK , just wait a little bit and you will se the update , it is completely normal !

Comment: But Notifiaction is Not come . Any User How can Know my Application New Version Available On Play store. Please clear these things